# port python code to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, porting

```
indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
```

Hope someone helps.

Comment: not familiar with python, so am not sure what this does. Seems like it could be explained in a sentence. Then I could try to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly new to Python but if I understand the code correctly, it reconstructs a list from a given offset into every item following offset+1 and the item at the offset.

Running it seems to confirm this:

```
>>> indices = ['one','two','three','four','five','six']
>>> i = 2
>>> indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
>>> indices
['one', 'two', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'three']
```

In Javascript can be written:

```
indices = indices.concat( indices.splice( i, 1 ) );
```

Same entire sequence would go:

```
>>> var indices = ['one','two','three','four','five','six'];
>>> var i = 2;
>>> indices = indices.concat( indices.splice( i, 1 ) );
>>> indices
["one", "two", "four", "five", "six", "three"]
```

This works because [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is destructive to the array but returns removed elements, which may then be handed to [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: Is it obvious that the last sentence is contrived just to fit in some links to the methods on MDC? :-)

Comment: It is an imaginary command line. I ran the code with FireBug but added the >>> in the end simply to make it look the same as the Python block. :-)

Comment: @Borgar, I will buy your imaginary command line. How much does it cost, in Quatloos?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var temp=indices.slice(i+1).concat(indices.slice(i, i+1));
var arr=[];
for (var j=0; j<temp.length; j++){
   arr[j+i]=temp[i];
}
```